# How Docker Swarm works with Docker Desktop on WSL2?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-swarm, wsl-2

I'm trying to build a system to collect data from some sensors on a bunch of Raspberry Pi 3.

In order to do that, I have created a docker-compose file with a bunch of services that I plan to distribute using Docker Swarm, but a few seconds after joining the worker node, using `docker node ls` on the manager, I always find the worker node in status `down`.

This is what I have already tried:

Initial setup used for testing:

- 2 Windows 11 PCs on the same local network
- Docker Desktop with WSL2 backend on both
- The first PC is a custom desktop connected via Ethernet
- The second is a Surface Pro 8 connected via WiFi
- Before every try, I opened the following ports on both PCs: 2377 TCP, 7946 TCP/UDP, 4789 UDP

First try (based on this [guide](https://oscarchou.com/posts/troubleshoot/fail-join-swarm-manager-node-in-wsl/)):

1. Run `docker swarm init` on the desktop PC
2. Run `docker run --rm -d -p 0.0.0.0:2378:2378 --name swarm-manager-proxy alpine/socat tcp-l:2378,fork,reuseaddr tcp:<IP-INIT>:2377` using the IP obtained with the first command (usually was 192.168.65.4)
3. Run `docker swarm join --token <TOKEN> <MANAGER-LOCAL-IP>:2378` on the SP8 using the IP of the desktop in the local network

Result: The connection succeeds, but after a few seconds, using `docker node ls`, I find the worker node in `down` status, and with `docker node inspect <WORKER-ID>`, I find the `heartbeat failure` status.

Second try: Swapped manager and worker PC, obtained the same results

Third try:

1. Installed Ubuntu on the desktop PC
2. Installed Docker following this [guide](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/api-connect/5.0.x?topic=environment-setting-up-docker-swarm-runtime) till point 3
3. Connected the SP8 as a worker

Result: Same as before

Fourth try: Reinstalled Docker Desktop on the SP8, same result as before

Fifth try: Swapped manager/worker role, using the alpine/socat container workaround on the SP8 (still with Ubuntu on the desktop)

Result: THE WORKER NODE (desktop) STAYS ACTIVE!

In this setup, I'm able to deploy a stack using a docker-compose file; the services get started correctly on the desired machines, but I was not able to verify if they are able to communicate via the overlay network.

So, at this point, I understand nothing about what is going on. Could someone explain to me if this is due to some limitations inside Docker Swarm using WSL2 or if I'm doing something wrong?